# texture isnt working

Tags: texturing

So I just started learning how to use Blender, and I put texture on the walls, but it doesn't show it, the texture works on the floor but on the walls, it only shows the color. how do I fix this? Also I don't know how to make the floor 3d, I watched some videos but it doesn't work (I have no idea what I'm doing).[image]

Comment: Hello maybe you need to unwrap your object?

Comment: it worked! thank you!

Comment: For the record - the "floor" works because you used a base plane (primitive object) which comes by default with its own (already unwrapped) UV map (as do most primitive objects). When you extruded the walls up from the floor (which is what I'm assuming you did) - the new "walls" don't have any UV (texture space) information associated with them yet. This is why it's necessary to unwrap any created geometry in order for textures to work properly.